# Creating a boolean panda dataframe from a list within a list

Tags: list, dataframe, boolean

```
[(['Piano'], 'Beethoven - opus22 4.mid'), (['Piano'], 'Borodin - ps7.mid'), (['Piano'], 'Chopin  - op18.mid'), ([None, 'Guitar', 'StringInstrument', 'Acoustic Bass'], 'Cyndi Lauper - True Colors.mid'), (['Piano', 'Fretless Bass', 'StringInstrument', None], 'Frank Mills - Musicbox Dancer.mid'), (['Piano', 'Acoustic Bass', None, 'Baritone Saxophone'], 'George Benson - On Broadway.mid'), (['Piano'], 'Grieg - Voeglein.mid'), (['Piano'], 'Mozart - 333 3.mid'), ([None, 'Pan Flute', 'Piano', 'Piccolo', 'Violin'], 'The Corrs - Dreams.mid'), (['Piano', None, 'Fretless Bass'], 'ABBA - Money Money Money.mid')]
```

The above-given list is a list of songs with the given instruments used within those songs. I want to make a boolean panda dataframe given these songs with the nonetype instrument removed. The below-given image as an example:

[Given dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2i5U.png)

I tried to make a dataframe given every single instrument and merge these, however, this did not result in the given dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    (["Piano"], "Beethoven - opus22 4.mid"),
    (["Piano"], "Borodin - ps7.mid"),
    (["Piano"], "Chopin - op18.mid"),
    (
        [None, "Guitar", "StringInstrument", "Acoustic Bass"],
        "Cyndi Lauper - True Colors.mid",
    ),
    (
        ["Piano", "Fretless Bass", "StringInstrument", None],
        "Frank Mills - Musicbox Dancer.mid",
    ),
    (
        ["Piano", "Acoustic Bass", None, "Baritone Saxophone"],
        "George Benson - On Broadway.mid",
    ),
    (["Piano"], "Grieg - Voeglein.mid"),
    (["Piano"], "Mozart - 333 3.mid"),
    (
        [None, "Pan Flute", "Piano", "Piccolo", "Violin"],
        "The Corrs - Dreams.mid",
    ),
    (["Piano", None, "Fretless Bass"], "ABBA - Money Money Money.mid"),
]

all_data = []
for instruments, title in lst:
    d = {"title": title}
    for i in instruments:
        if not i is None:
            d[i] = 1
    all_data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).fillna(0).set_index("title").astype(int)
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                   Piano  Guitar  StringInstrument  Acoustic Bass  Fretless Bass  Baritone Saxophone  Pan Flute  Piccolo  Violin
Beethoven - opus22 4.mid               1       0                 0              0              0                   0          0        0       0
Borodin - ps7.mid                      1       0                 0              0              0                   0          0        0       0
Chopin - op18.mid                      1       0                 0              0              0                   0          0        0       0
Cyndi Lauper - True Colors.mid         0       1                 1              1              0                   0          0        0       0
Frank Mills - Musicbox Dancer.mid      1       0                 1              0              1                   0          0        0       0
George Benson - On Broadway.mid        1       0                 0              1              0                   1          0        0       0
Grieg - Voeglein.mid                   1       0                 0              0              0                   0          0        0       0
Mozart - 333 3.mid                     1       0                 0              0              0                   0          0        0       0
The Corrs - Dreams.mid                 1       0                 0              0              0                   0          1        1       1
ABBA - Money Money Money.mid           1       0                 0              0              1                   0          0        0       0
```